# HTML soundboard has ghost boxes in Chrome

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a simple soundboard and currently the formatting works fine in IE9 but in Chrome is has strange boxes that I believe are generated by the script to play the sounds. I can't figure out how to get rid of them.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Soundboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="doc">
        <h1>Soundboard</h1>
        <!-- JS here to prevent 'flash' of all the default audio players -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
           $(function() {
                $("audio").removeAttr("controls").each(function(i, audioElement) {
                    var audio = $(this);
                    var that = this; //closure to keep reference to current audio tag
                    $("#doc").append($('<button>'+audio.attr("title")+'</button>').click(function() {
                        that.play();
                    }));
                });
            });
        </script>
                                <audio src="audio/emintro.mp3" controls autobuffer="true" title="Murray!"></audio>
                                <audio src="audio/emitheme.mp3" controls autobuffer="true" title="Intro"></audio>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like Chrome is trying to display the play/pause and other buttons - as you've defined in your `controls` parameter. It's just being handled differently. The `<audio>` tag is new, and not supported equally.

I'd just hide the audio elements and create my own buttons for playing them, that way you define and control the UI.